# Wordpress Dashboard redirect for specific User Role

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I'm successfully using this code to redirect */wp-admin/index.php* (WP Dashboard) to another specific Admin page.
I would now like to limit this action to a specific user role (i.e Author).

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {

    global $pagenow;

    # Check current admin page.
    if ( $pagenow == 'index.php' ) {

        wp_redirect( admin_url( '/admin.php?page=wuapc-page-376' ) );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-role

Comment: Thank you. I did search for it before asking. Maybe I didn't use the right keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [wp_get_current_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {

    global $pagenow;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    # Check current admin page.
    if ( $pagenow == 'index.php' && in_array('author', $user->roles)) {

        wp_redirect( admin_url( '/admin.php?page=wuapc-page-376' ) );
        exit;
    }
} );
```